# Подключение файла грамматики для распознавания речи на Python - pocketsphinx

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

Задача - реализовать приложения, которое бы распознавало голосовые команды из аудиофайла, с подключением своего словаря и файла грамматики.

Установка pocketsphinx была следующей

```
sudo apt-get install swig
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
sudo apt install libasound2-dev
pip install pocketsphinx
```

Код

```js
import os
from pocketsphinx import AudioFile, get_model_path, get_data_path

model_path = get_model_path()
data_path = get_data_path()

config = {
    'verbose': True,
    'audio_file': os.path.join(data_path, '/home/mmamonova/sphinx/audio/record-1544774411160.wav'),
    'buffer_size': 2048,
    'no_search': False,
    'full_utt': False,
    'hmm': os.path.join(model_path, 'zero_ru.cd_cont_4000'),
    'lm': False,
    'jsgf': os.path.join(model_path, 'grammar.jsgf'),
    'dict': os.path.join(model_path, 'dictionary.dic'),
}
audio = AudioFile(**config)
for phrase in audio:
    print(phrase)
```

выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app.py", line 65, in <module>
    audio = AudioFile(**config)
  File "/home/mmamonova/sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 169, in __init__
    super(AudioFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mmamonova/sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 90, in __init__
    super(Pocketsphinx, self).__init__(config)
  File "/home/mmamonova/sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py", line 275, in __init__
    this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Эта проблема возникает только если прописан путь к файлу грамматики (jsfd). Если пользоваться стандартной языковой моделью, всё работает (но качество распознавания отвратительное).

Подскажите, как это решить и подключить грамматику?

Все действия выполняются в виртуальной среде приложения.

Детализация ошибки показала, что :

```
 ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 141: The word 'экран' is missing in the dictionary
```

Файл грамматики

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar commands;
<action> = (включить | выключить | опустить | поднять);
<device> = (проектор | экран | звук | презентацию);
public <commands> = <action> <device>;
```

Словарь

```
включить v k ll uj ch i tt
выключить v y k ll uj ch ii tt
проектор p r ay i k t oo r
экран Э k r ay n
звук z v uu k
опустить a p u ss tt ii tt
поднять p a d nn ja tt
презентацию p rr i zz i n t aa c y uj
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, в словаре присутствуют проблемы с транскрипцией и символами. Правильная запись транскрипции и символов в словаре pocketsphinx включает в себя использование символов для интонации и долгих звуков. Кроме того, транскрипция должна соответствовать фонетическим правилам русского языка.

Попробуйте использовать словарь

```
включить V K L U CH I T'
выключить V Y K L U CH II T'
проектор P R AY K T O R
экран EH K R AH N
звук Z V U K
опустить A P U S T' II T'
поднять P A D N J A T'
презентацию P R Y EH Z EH N T AH T S Y UJ
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]